# Installing Octave on CentOS - incompatible BLAS library error

Tags: centos, software-installation, yum, fortran

I am trying to install Octave on CentOS. After running

```
sudo yum install octave
./configure F77=gfortran
```

I got this error:

```
configure: error: A BLAS library was detected but found incompatible with your Fortran 77 compiler settings.
```

After some googling followed up with this:

```
sudo yum-builddep octave
sudo yum install lapack64-devel lapack64
sudo yum install libblas-dev libatlas-dev liblapack-dev
```

And yet I'm still getting the same BLAS incompatibility error.

Could you advise on how to proceed?

Comment: What happens if you use `F77=g77` instead? (You may have to install the `compat-gcc-34-g77` (or similar name for your version of CentOS) package.)

Comment: @John: getting the same error: `configure: error: A BLAS library was detected but found incompatible with your Fortran 77 compiler settings.`

Answer (score 1):

I was encountering the same issue for a significant amount of time until I installed the following packages:

```
sudo yum install lapack-devel
sudo yum install atlas-devel
```

Once those were installed, ./configure ran without any errors. I didn't have to use F77= either, but that may differ in your situation.

From there, you should be able to run `make && make install` without errors.